# not able to set process.env.PORT variable in windows for node

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require('express'); 
const api = express();

api.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

api.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to port 
${port}`));
```

I am using this command to
set `PORT=5000`
After setting it stills show Listening  to port 3000

Comment: 1) process.env.PORT uppercase... 2) you are setting it to 3000 if you want 5000 then it’s process.env.PORT || 5000

Comment: `// I am using this command to set set PORT=5000 After setting it stills show Listening to port 3000`. Where is the command?

Comment: `PORT=5000 node <filename>`

Comment: set PORT=5000 <-- this is the command

Answer (score 22):

You must run your file with the same CLI program (and instance) you used to set the variable value.

- In Command Prompt: `set PORT=5000`
- In Power Shell: `$env:PORT=5000`
- In Bash (Windows): `export PORT=5000`

After that, run your program `node app.js` and it works.

If you're using the integrated terminal of VSCode to run your file, but using another CLI program (or instance) to set the value of `PORT`, is not going to work unless you change that value permanently by using `setx PORT 5000` either with the Command Prompt or Power Shell (I don't know how to do it from Bash for Windows). In that case, you would need to restart VSCode for running your file with the last value of `PORT`.

Answer (score 8):

It should be like this

```
For Command Prompt: set PORT=5000
For Power Shell: $env:PORT=5000
For Bash (Windows): export PORT=5000
```

Not like this

```
For Command Prompt: set PORT = 5000
For Power Shell: $env:PORT = 5000
For Bash (Windows): export PORT = 5000
```

i.e. no space before and after `=` sign.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using powershell or vscode terminal

```
$env:PORT=5000
```

if you are using windows command prompt

```
set PORT=5000
```

if you are using Bash or MAC terminal

```
export PORT=5000
```

for me i am using vscode terminal and $env:PORT=5000 is working fine.
[image: setting listen port to 5000 as env variable]

Comment: no space before and after = sign.

Answer (score 1):

use `set PORT=5000` in **command prompt** rather than **vscode terminal**. It surely will work.

Answer (score 0):

const port = **Number**(process.env.PORT)

I don't know if we had the same problem, or if you ever figured this out, but I made an account **JUST** for this because I could not **for the life of me** get process.env.PORT to work, even though I was following everyone's code to the tee (no one else seems to have to explicitly convert process.env.PORT to a number). Needed to fix this problem in order to deploy my app on Heroku, which assigns the PORT variable. Can happily say it works and not lose sleep tonight :)

Comment: `process.env` variables are always of type `string | undefined`. You might consider taking a look at Typescript to avoid those kind of mistakes in the future.

Comment: @Almaju Oh I never knew about TypeScript! I will definitely try out the TS Check in my next project, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it gives an error like:
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

use this command prompt (Windows):

```
set PORT=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing dotenv solved the issue for me.

```bash
npm I dotenv
```

and then add this to your js file

```
require('dotenv').config()
```